# How to insert rows without duplicate in Postgresql, when new rows themselves has duplicate?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

Postgresql 10.1 + Node.js 8.9.1

I have a table of about 1.5M rows which has a text column of about 150~1500 words.
Now I have to insert about 10K new rows, there are probably duplicates in new rows, and between new rows and old rows.

I want to make sure that there is no duplicate or nearly the same texts.
For now I'm using smlar to calculate similarity between texts of two rows.

Is there another way to inserts new rows, must I create a temporary table to store new rows, and do two queries before inserting one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define similarity. What is the criteria to determine whether two texts are similar?

Comment: `must I create a temporary table to store new rows... ` Yes. 1) import into this temp 2) dedup this temp 3) delete from temp where exists(select 1 from big_table where similar 4) insert into big_table(...) select ... from temp. 5) drop tmp

Comment: @LajosArpad something like this `tsvector2textarray(tv) % tsvector2textarray(NEW.tv)`, tv is a column that stores the tsvector of text

Comment: @joop I guess so, I'm expecting that someone could come up with a simpler or faster solution

Comment: How do you know it would be slow? Could it be faster? (answer: no) Why *should* it be faster? Could it be simpler? (answer: no)

Comment: Can you give us a definition instead of an example?